# Eclipse RCP: How to set launch parameters?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

You need to set the path to the directory "splash_v1" in plugin "com.project.console". Example without directory "splash_v1":

```
osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/com.project.console
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please edit the question so that potential answerers know exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to define launch parameters when starting up your RCP application you have two options.

1. Define them in the Run Configuration (configurable via Project > Run Configurations)
2. Define them at startup by passing them in with the executable from the console (e.g., `./myrcp -application myrcp`).

For an overview of runtime options, cf. [The Eclipse runtime options](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html).